# WPF app getting crashed outside of visual studio only on few systems

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dll, kernel

I have  a wpf app which is being converted to uwp app using visual studio windows application packaging project and it is getting crashed on Launch in few of the systems. I am not able to figure out what the problem is. I tried debugging the app using WinDbgPreview. I am attaching the details below.

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.18972.1001 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

*** wait with pending attach

************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 00fc0000 0112e000   FolensHIVE.exe
ModLoad: 77800000 7799a000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 62d50000 62da2000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MSCOREE.DLL
ModLoad: 76580000 76660000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\KERNEL32.dll
ModLoad: 758a0000 75a9c000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\KERNELBASE.dll
(20a0.2f48): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
eax=00000000 ebx=013e7000 ecx=832d0000 edx=00000000 esi=01802298 edi=7780688c
eip=778ae9d2 esp=014ff894 ebp=014ff8c0 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2b:
778ae9d2 cc              int     3
0:000> g
ModLoad: 77620000 77699000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ADVAPI32.dll
ModLoad: 75ac0000 75b7f000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll
ModLoad: 76be0000 76c56000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
ModLoad: 76cc0000 76d7b000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\RPCRT4.dll
ModLoad: 74fd0000 74ff0000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\SspiCli.dll
ModLoad: 74fc0000 74fca000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\CRYPTBASE.dll
ModLoad: 773a0000 773ff000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\bcryptPrimitives.dll
ModLoad: 64d60000 64ded000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
ModLoad: 775d0000 77614000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\SHLWAPI.dll
ModLoad: 76150000 763c6000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\combase.dll
ModLoad: 76e80000 76f9f000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll
ModLoad: 76550000 76571000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\GDI32.dll
ModLoad: 76e60000 76e77000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\win32u.dll
ModLoad: 77090000 771ea000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\gdi32full.dll
ModLoad: 77770000 777ec000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\msvcp_win.dll
ModLoad: 75090000 75225000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\USER32.dll
ModLoad: 77400000 77425000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\IMM32.DLL
ModLoad: 776a0000 776af000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll
ModLoad: 742c0000 742c8000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\VERSION.dll
ModLoad: 60320000 60ad0000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
ModLoad: 64d40000 64d54000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\VCRUNTIME140_CLR0400.dll
ModLoad: 64c90000 64d3b000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ucrtbase_clr0400.dll
(20a0.2f48): Unknown exception - code 04242420 (first chance)
ModLoad: 77080000 77086000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\psapi.dll
ModLoad: 5ef10000 6031c000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\e69bd360f052898b652ab44c060ce643\mscorlib.ni.dll
ModLoad: 77240000 77337000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ole32.dll
ModLoad: 6fdf0000 6fe6a000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll
CLR:(C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll) Rejecting native image because native image dependency C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll had a different identity than expected
ModLoad: 5e4b0000 5ef03000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\6cbffa49d65828744c9c28008185bdb7\System.ni.dll
ModLoad: 5dc90000 5e4a8000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Core\98e1e8cab4a10a9028b5417d87ca1d51\System.Core.ni.dll
ModLoad: 618a0000 61cbc000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\WindowsBase\0edca6007c5c28f4b080d0b66bdefa05\WindowsBase.ni.dll
ModLoad: 75860000 75873000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\CRYPTSP.dll
ModLoad: 72220000 7224f000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\rsaenh.dll
ModLoad: 75aa0000 75ab9000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\bcrypt.dll
ModLoad: 5d050000 5dc87000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\PresentationCore\a4c01d2e2144846e05ace1a451781dce\PresentationCore.ni.dll
ModLoad: 5bc70000 5d046000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Presentatio5ae0f00f#\d63bb278d1e02be7ee254a65edf90b97\PresentationFramework.ni.dll
ModLoad: 64a80000 64c83000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xaml\0f725eb82624879cdc49cde97f75bc3f\System.Xaml.ni.dll
ModLoad: 5b9f0000 5bc70000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dwrite.dll
ModLoad: 5b860000 5b9ed000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\wpfgfx_v0400.dll
ModLoad: 74ff0000 75082000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\OLEAUT32.dll
ModLoad: 61830000 6189b000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MSVCP140_CLR0400.dll
ModLoad: 5b770000 5b853000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\PresentationNative_v0400.dll
ModLoad: 5b6e0000 5b769000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
ModLoad: 5b5d0000 5b6d5000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Configuration\f191daccb06325e80fb65876c7ec847f\System.Configuration.ni.dll
ModLoad: 5ae50000 5b5c4000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xml\7898f6e777383930e5e76fc058a9671a\System.Xml.ni.dll
ModLoad: 76660000 76bd8000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\shell32.dll
ModLoad: 77490000 774cb000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll
ModLoad: 76d80000 76e04000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\shcore.dll
ModLoad: 75b80000 76144000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\windows.storage.dll
ModLoad: 752e0000 752f7000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\profapi.dll
ModLoad: 76e10000 76e53000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll
ModLoad: 763d0000 763dd000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\UMPDC.dll
ModLoad: 75750000 75853000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MSCTF.dll
ModLoad: 062f0000 06378000   vm.dll  
ModLoad: 06380000 06408000   vm.dll  
ModLoad: 06340000 0634a000   MvvmFoundation.Wpf.dll
ModLoad: 06350000 0635a000   MvvmFoundation.Wpf.dll
ModLoad: 06710000 0674c000   sharedlib.dll
ModLoad: 06750000 0678c000   sharedlib.dll
ModLoad: 06340000 0634e000   image06340000
ModLoad: 06360000 0636e000   image06360000
ModLoad: 06340000 0634a000   Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics.dll
ModLoad: 06370000 0637a000   Microsoft.AppCenter.Analytics.dll
ModLoad: 06710000 06734000   Microsoft.AppCenter.dll
ModLoad: 06790000 067b4000   Microsoft.AppCenter.dll
ModLoad: 06340000 06350000   Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.dll
ModLoad: 06710000 06720000   Microsoft.AppCenter.Crashes.dll
ModLoad: 76fa0000 77020000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll
ModLoad: 64e10000 64eba000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.ApplicationModel.dll
ModLoad: 67f00000 680e4000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\twinapi.appcore.dll
ModLoad: 6b860000 6b87f000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\RMCLIENT.dll
ModLoad: 6b910000 6b9ea000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WinTypes.dll
ModLoad: 067c0000 067e2000   image067c0000
ModLoad: 06a00000 06a22000   image06a00000
ModLoad: 06730000 06741000   image06730000
ModLoad: 067c0000 067d1000   image067c0000
ModLoad: 06730000 06738000   image06730000
ModLoad: 06740000 06748000   image06740000
ModLoad: 06730000 0673a000   System.Runtime.dll
ModLoad: 067e0000 067ea000   System.Runtime.dll
ModLoad: 61810000 6182f000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\netstandard\9da3a5eb6cc58d6ac657f76f55766062\netstandard.ni.dll
ModLoad: 77080000 77086000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\psapi.dll
ModLoad: 5ae00000 5ae42000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.dll
ModLoad: 74450000 74515000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\propsys.dll
ModLoad: 617f0000 61803000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\mssprxy.dll
ModLoad: 74410000 74442000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\iphlpapi.dll
ModLoad: 71ba0000 71c31000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\DNSAPI.dll
ModLoad: 77430000 7748e000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WS2_32.dll
ModLoad: 77750000 77757000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\NSI.dll
ModLoad: 71c40000 71c53000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
ModLoad: 71b80000 71b95000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dhcpcsvc.DLL
ModLoad: 6b880000 6b888000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WINNSI.DLL
ModLoad: 70230000 703db000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\urlmon.dll
ModLoad: 70000000 70229000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\iertutil.dll
ModLoad: 06e60000 06f0a000   Newtonsoft.Json.dll
ModLoad: 06f10000 06fba000   Newtonsoft.Json.dll
ModLoad: 5ac50000 5adf3000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Drawing\fb9a09aa3b949e87144af9fda1977ba8\System.Drawing.ni.dll
ModLoad: 59de0000 5ac43000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\7c8f0783ebc11b1d737509d2d7d3247d\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll
ModLoad: 71c60000 71cb2000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\mswsock.dll
ModLoad: 07560000 0757c000   image07560000
ModLoad: 076c0000 076dc000   image076c0000
ModLoad: 07410000 07418000   System.Threading.Tasks.dll
ModLoad: 07560000 07568000   System.Threading.Tasks.dll
ModLoad: 076e0000 076e8000   System.Collections.dll
ModLoad: 076f0000 076f8000   System.Collections.dll
ModLoad: 07410000 07418000   System.Threading.dll
ModLoad: 07570000 07578000   System.Threading.dll
ModLoad: 07700000 07712000   SQLitePCLRaw.core.dll
ModLoad: 07720000 07732000   SQLitePCLRaw.core.dll
ModLoad: 07410000 07418000   SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll
ModLoad: 076e0000 076e8000   SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll
ModLoad: 07700000 07714000   SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl.dll
ModLoad: 07740000 07754000   SQLitePCLRaw.provider.dynamic_cdecl.dll
ModLoad: 07760000 07786000   System.Memory.dll
ModLoad: 07790000 077b6000   System.Memory.dll
ModLoad: 07710000 07718000   SQLitePCLRaw.nativelibrary.dll
ModLoad: 07760000 07768000   SQLitePCLRaw.nativelibrary.dll
ModLoad: 07710000 0771a000   System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll
ModLoad: 07770000 0777a000   System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll
ModLoad: 59ce0000 59dd5000   C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\FolensPublishingCompany.FolensHIVE_1.0.29.0_x86__9r3t3jamfgx9p\magicbox\runtimes\win-x86\native\e_sqlite3.dll
ModLoad: 077e0000 077e8000   System.Runtime.Extensions.dll
ModLoad: 077f0000 077f8000   System.Runtime.Extensions.dll
ModLoad: 077e0000 077e8000   image077e0000
ModLoad: 07800000 07808000   image07800000
ModLoad: 077e0000 077e8000   System.Linq.dll
ModLoad: 07810000 07818000   System.Linq.dll
ModLoad: 077e0000 077e8000   System.Reflection.dll
ModLoad: 07820000 07828000   System.Reflection.dll
ModLoad: 077e0000 077e8000   System.Reflection.Extensions.dll
ModLoad: 07830000 07838000   System.Reflection.Extensions.dll
(20a0.2a9c): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(20a0.2a9c): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.2a9c): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(20a0.2a9c): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.2a9c): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(20a0.2a9c): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.2a9c): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(20a0.2a9c): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.2a9c): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
ModLoad: 59bd0000 59cd5000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\diasymreader.dll
ModLoad: 077e0000 077e8000   System.Linq.Expressions.dll
ModLoad: 07840000 07848000   System.Linq.Expressions.dll
(20a0.2a9c): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(20a0.2a9c): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
ModLoad: 07860000 07868000   System.Globalization.dll
ModLoad: 07870000 07878000   System.Globalization.dll
(20a0.2a9c): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(20a0.2a9c): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.2a9c): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(20a0.2a9c): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.2a9c): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(20a0.2a9c): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.2a9c): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(20a0.2a9c): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.2a9c): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(20a0.2a9c): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.2a9c): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(20a0.2a9c): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.2a9c): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(20a0.2a9c): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.2a9c): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(20a0.2a9c): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.2a9c): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(20a0.2a9c): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
ModLoad: 59aa0000 59bd0000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Management\d6b21b4e4f49b98b955d89d8d073ebc0\System.Management.ni.dll
ModLoad: 6d8c0000 6d8dd000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\wbem\wmiutils.dll
ModLoad: 633e0000 63449000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\wbemcomn.dll
ModLoad: 6d110000 6d11d000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\wbem\wbemprox.dll
ModLoad: 59a70000 59a91000   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\wminet_utils.dll
ModLoad: 6a6f0000 6a700000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\wbem\wbemsvc.dll
ModLoad: 63310000 633db000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\wbem\fastprox.dll
ModLoad: 6a620000 6a62f000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\amsi.dll
ModLoad: 74cb0000 74cce000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\USERENV.dll
ModLoad: 63180000 63302000   C:\Program Files (x86)\Kaspersky Lab\Kaspersky Endpoint Security for Windows\antimalware_provider.dll
ModLoad: 774d0000 775cb000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\CRYPT32.dll
ModLoad: 77760000 7776e000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MSASN1.dll
ModLoad: 742b0000 742b8000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\DPAPI.DLL
ModLoad: 6a4b0000 6a619000   C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.18362.356_none_5f5cd939821dcaa0\gdiplus.dll
ModLoad: 59790000 59a63000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Runteb92aa12#\e1f8543ba021d452b8b620b1750e8e13\System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll
ModLoad: 59740000 59787000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Numerics\d4f8d095e847003caadccf2faef1b04a\System.Numerics.ni.dll
ModLoad: 58f20000 59739000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Data\aef9848217290bc0d5b9916cede9856a\System.Data.ni.dll
ModLoad: 58bc0000 58f14000   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll
(20a0.2f2c): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(20a0.2f2c): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.2f2c): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(20a0.2f2c): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
ModLoad: 07fc0000 08024000   CefSharpHelper.dll
ModLoad: 08030000 08094000   CefSharpHelper.dll
ModLoad: 07dc0000 07dce000   CefSharp.WinForms.dll
ModLoad: 07fc0000 07fce000   CefSharp.WinForms.dll
ModLoad: 58a80000 58bb8000   CefSharp.Core.dll
ModLoad: 080a0000 081d8000   CefSharp.Core.dll
ModLoad: 58a80000 58bb8000   C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\FolensPublishingCompany.FolensHIVE_1.0.29.0_x86__9r3t3jamfgx9p\magicbox\CefSharp.Core.dll
ModLoad: 617d0000 617e5000   C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\FolensPublishingCompany.FolensHIVE_1.0.29.0_x86__9r3t3jamfgx9p\magicbox\VCRUNTIME140.dll
ModLoad: 58a10000 58a7f000   C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\FolensPublishingCompany.FolensHIVE_1.0.29.0_x86__9r3t3jamfgx9p\magicbox\MSVCP140.dll
ModLoad: 530f0000 58a10000   C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\FolensPublishingCompany.FolensHIVE_1.0.29.0_x86__9r3t3jamfgx9p\magicbox\libcef.dll
ModLoad: 75230000 752e0000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\COMDLG32.dll
ModLoad: 74c60000 74c84000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WINMM.dll
ModLoad: 72cd0000 72cda000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\Secur32.dll
ModLoad: 72cb0000 72cc3000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\NETAPI32.dll
ModLoad: 74d70000 74dfd000   C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.18362.356_none_71d539095ae5ad3b\COMCTL32.dll
ModLoad: 67b40000 67b93000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\OLEACC.dll
ModLoad: 73fc0000 73fcf000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WTSAPI32.dll
ModLoad: 53050000 530e9000   C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\FolensPublishingCompany.FolensHIVE_1.0.29.0_x86__9r3t3jamfgx9p\magicbox\chrome_elf.dll
ModLoad: 65de0000 65deb000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\HID.DLL
ModLoad: 6c2c0000 6c44f000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dbghelp.dll
ModLoad: 74530000 745f1000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dxgi.dll
ModLoad: 74b00000 74b25000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll
ModLoad: 52ec0000 5304e000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\d3d9.dll
ModLoad: 52e80000 52e97000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\USP10.dll
ModLoad: 52ea0000 52ebc000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dxva2.dll
ModLoad: 67170000 6734e000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\d3d11.dll
ModLoad: 71d00000 71dbe000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WINHTTP.dll
ModLoad: 6a4a0000 6a4ad000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\credui.dll
ModLoad: 74730000 7479b000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WINSPOOL.DRV
ModLoad: 6f370000 6f3af000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\CRYPTUI.dll
ModLoad: 746e0000 74703000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WINMMBASE.dll
ModLoad: 69170000 69191000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ncrypt.dll
ModLoad: 08000000 08023000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll
ModLoad: 743f0000 74409000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dxcore.dll
ModLoad: 08000000 08019000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dxcore.dll
ModLoad: 687c0000 687e8000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\NTASN1.dll
ModLoad: 72ca0000 72cab000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\NETUTILS.DLL
ModLoad: 72810000 72825000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\SAMCLI.DLL
ModLoad: 08490000 084c6000   CefSharp.dll
ModLoad: 084d0000 08506000   CefSharp.dll
ModLoad: 6ea10000 6ea26000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\NLAapi.dll
ModLoad: 71740000 71789000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WINSTA.dll
ModLoad: 6f220000 6f273000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\wlanapi.dll
ModLoad: 52e10000 52e76000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\MMDevApi.dll
ModLoad: 74210000 74233000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\DEVOBJ.dll
ModLoad: 74cd0000 74d64000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\mscms.dll
ModLoad: 74710000 74721000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ColorAdapterClient.dll
ModLoad: 52d90000 52e06000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\daxexec.dll
(20a0.33f8): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
ModLoad: 74c20000 74c28000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\FLTLIB.DLL
(20a0.33f8): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.33f8): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(20a0.33f8): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.1bcc): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.1bcc): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.1bcc): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.1bcc): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
ModLoad: 52d50000 52d84000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\container.dll
ModLoad: 52c50000 52d50000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Windows.UI.dll
ModLoad: 6be30000 6beb4000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\TextInputFramework.dll
ModLoad: 52b90000 52c43000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\InputHost.dll
ModLoad: 6bb40000 6bbc9000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CoreMessaging.dll
ModLoad: 6bbd0000 6be2e000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CoreUIComponents.dll
ModLoad: 74280000 742a9000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ntmarta.dll
ModLoad: 64ec0000 64f00000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\capauthz.dll
ModLoad: 771f0000 77236000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WINTRUST.dll
ModLoad: 0c000000 0c00a000   FocusVMLib.dll
ModLoad: 0c030000 0c03a000   FocusVMLib.dll
ModLoad: 529f0000 52b88000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Microsoft.CSharp\44adb1560fc334dd99553557b64f381d\Microsoft.CSharp.ni.dll
ModLoad: 528b0000 52915000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Dynamic\91cbc53c5aa1cc08c69c5967c14a73b6\System.Dynamic.ni.dll
(20a0.2f48): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.2f48): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.2f48): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
ModLoad: 52740000 528a9000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\WindowsCodecs.dll
ModLoad: 78410000 7bb1e000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\ki124455.inf_amd64_0f9ddfab4df0266d\igdumdim32.dll
ModLoad: 75300000 75749000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\SETUPAPI.dll
ModLoad: 526b0000 5273c000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Presentatioaec034ca#\f7a78d3b0fe885d28ff288fdd157cffc\PresentationFramework.Aero2.ni.dll
ModLoad: 520d0000 52117000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\WindowsForm0b574481#\1f1aaa20430bc2c109e17d2ce724bc93\WindowsFormsIntegration.ni.dll
ModLoad: 0c190000 0c1c8000   model.dll
ModLoad: 0c1d0000 0c208000   model.dll
ModLoad: 50ae0000 50bbe000   System.Data.SQLite.dll
ModLoad: 0c210000 0c2ee000   System.Data.SQLite.dll
ModLoad: 50ae0000 50bbe000   C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\FolensPublishingCompany.FolensHIVE_1.0.29.0_x86__9r3t3jamfgx9p\magicbox\System.Data.SQLite.dll
(20a0.2f48): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(20a0.2f48): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(20a0.2f48): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(20a0.2f48): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(20a0.2f48): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(20a0.2f48): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.2f48): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(20a0.2f48): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.2f48): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.2f48): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.2f48): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.2f48): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.2f48): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.2f48): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.2f48): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.2f48): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.2f48): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.2f48): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
ModLoad: 6a630000 6a661000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dataexchange.dll
ModLoad: 67350000 674b9000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\dcomp.dll
(20a0.2054): C++ EH exception - code e06d7363 (first chance)
(20a0.2054): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
ModLoad: 50ac0000 50ad8000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\msctfui.dll
ModLoad: 50a30000 50ab6000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\UIAutomationTypes\ba67dbcfff9890ec462767d4b8c02635\UIAutomationTypes.ni.dll
ModLoad: 50a10000 50a2b000   C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\UIAutomationProvider\f8bf8c4c519729a7a7ffcb893b92a07f\UIAutomationProvider.ni.dll
ModLoad: 50810000 50a03000   C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\UIAutomationCore.dll
(20a0.2f48): CLR exception - code e0434352 (first chance)
(20a0.2f48): Unknown exception - code c000041d (!!! second chance !!!)
eax=014fdc48 ebx=00000005 ecx=00000005 edx=00000000 esi=014fdd0c edi=00000001
eip=759b3522 esp=014fdc48 ebp=014fdca4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000216
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x62:
759b3522 8b4c2454        mov     ecx,dword ptr [esp+54h] ss:002b:014fdc9c=3ed71bf3
0:000> g
WARNING: Continuing a non-continuable exception
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000005 edx=00000000 esi=80131506 edi=7791da60
eip=7787203c esp=014fd37c ebp=014fd450 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000202
ntdll!NtTerminateProcess+0xc:
7787203c c20800          ret     8
0:000> g
       ^ No runnable debuggees error in 'g'
```

Also in event viewer I am getting this exception :

```
Application: FolensHIVE.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ArgumentException
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(System.Windows.DependencyProperty, System.Object, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata, Boolean, Boolean, System.Windows.OperationType, Boolean)
```

```
Faulting application name: FolensHIVE.exe, version: 2.2.0.56825, time stamp: 0x5d970775
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.18362.356, time stamp: 0x8c4198ab
Exception code: 0xe0434352
```

```
Faulting application name: FolensHIVE.exe, version: 2.2.0.56825, time stamp: 0x5d970775
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.18362.356, time stamp: 0x8c4198ab
Exception code: 0xc000041d
Fault offset: 0x00113522
Faulting process id: 0xc64
Faulting application start time: 0x01d57a9853250ff6
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\FolensPublishingCompany.FolensHIVE_1.0.29.0_x86__9r3t3jamfgx9p\magicbox\FolensHIVE.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 14bacc2d-28a5-486b-8a1c-970d675599c3
Faulting package full name: FolensPublishingCompany.FolensHIVE_1.0.29.0_x86__9r3t3jamfgx9p
Faulting package-relative application ID: App
```

Comment: The Net Library has to be the same on all systems (including updates) for code to run.  Otherwise, you need to publish to get target machines windows dlls to match the machine where code was compiled.

Comment: @jdweng I din't get. Can you please elaborate. I have complied the code with .Net Framework version 4.6.1 and I am trying to run the app on latest version of windows 10. And it is working fine on windows version 1903 on some systems correctly. while on another system having the same version of windows the app is crashing.

Comment: Many Net library methods are just wrappers that call Windows dlls.Windows dlls get updated from Microsoft periodically and there are different versions of the dlls that are installed on different machines (depending on installed software and machine manufactures).Net library installed on a machine also can be different from machine to machine.A Net Application calls both Net dll and Windows dlls.  So any differences in these dlls can cause crashes.Publishing an application creates a setup.exe and running setup will bring the dlls on deployed machine to be compatible with you c# application.

Comment: It looks like from exception you are using x86 mode.  Are you also using AnyCPU which will run on both Intel and AMD microprocessors?  It looks like the code is calling System32 modules and many machines running windows 10 are using mainly x64 windows dlls and may have obsolete version of dlls in the System32 folder.

Comment: You may just be able to replace the KERNELBASE.dll on depolyed machines.  On my Windows 10 machine I have a very new version from this summer version 10.0.16299.1268.  Here is the update info from Microsoft : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4507455/windows-10-update-kb4507455